# I realized that I am receiving conflicts when I use Font Awesome and Bootstrap social icons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-awesome

https://codepen.io/rogercodes/pen/JJVXoV/

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
```

CSS:

```
.fa {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
/* Add a hover effect if you want */
.fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

/* Set a specific color for each brand */

/* Facebook */
.fa-facebook {
    background: #3B5998;
    color: white;
}

/* Twitter */
.fa-twitter {
    background: #55ACEE;
    color: white;
}
```

Above is the link which currently has both Font Awesome and Bootstaps added under settings.

Here is the w3schools link that shows the correct icons only using font-awesome and not bootstrap.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_social_media_buttons.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Spharah said, all you have to do is remove the `width: 30px` rule for the `.fa` selector:

https://codepen.io/prahladyeri/pen/WOWwMz

[image]

(Or alternatively, change it to something like `70px` if you want to tackle the facebook icon being slightly narrower, due to its icon width. This way, both icons will be equal sized.)

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
.fa {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.fa-twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Style Social Media Buttons</h2>

<!-- Add font awesome icons -->
<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

**output-preview**:
[image]

this same script if i run in codepen it is giving same problem